# Operator bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect after trying to create new socket in geometry input

Tags: python, node-editor, geometry-nodes

i'm trying to create a  Geometry Nodes->group input->new socket and it just shows:

```
  File "C:\Users\a111\Documents\untitled.blend\Text", line 21, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\a111\Downloads\blender-3.1.2-candidate+v31.2cfca7d9101d-windows.amd64-release\blender-3.1.2-candidate+v31.2cfca7d9101d-windows.amd64-release\3.1\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 132, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Operator bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add.poll() failed, context is incorrect
Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console
```

Here is my main file:

```
import bpy
from imports import create_collection, move_all_to_coll, create_object, create_objects_from_list

# create 2 collections named "DISTRIBUTOR" and "CONTENTS"
create_collection("DISTRIBUTOR")
create_collection("CONTENTS")

# create objects in "SCENE Collection" - cube, sphere, cone, cylinder
create_objects_from_list('cube', 'sphere', 'cone', 'cylinder')
# move objects from main collection to "CONTENTS Collection"
move_all_to_coll("CONTENTS")

# create object in "DISTRIBUTOR Collection" - cube
create_object('cube')
# move cube to "DISTRIBUTOR Collection"
move_all_to_coll("DISTRIBUTOR")
# add geometry node to the cube with custom Group Inputs fields
bpy.context.active_object.modifiers.new("Group Input", 'NODES')
#bpy.data.node_groups['Geometry Nodes'].nodes["Group Input"]
bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add(in_out='IN')
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].active_input = 1
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[1].name = "Contents"
bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_change_type(in_out='IN', socket_type='NodeSocketCollection')
bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add(in_out='IN')
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].active_input = 2
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[2].name = "Min in group"
bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_change_type(in_out='IN', socket_type='NodeSocketInt')
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[2].min_value = 1
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[2].max_value = 3
bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add(in_out='IN')
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].active_input = 3
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[3].name = "Max in group"
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[3].default_value = 4
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[3].min_value = 4
bpy.data.node_groups["Geometry Nodes.001"].inputs[3].max_value = 6
```

These are my imports:

````
# function that creates objects, obj can be a tuple of objects
def create_objects_from_list(*objs):
    for obj in objs:
        create_object(obj)


def create_object(obj):
    # dict of avalaible objects
    objects = {
        "cube": bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cube_add,
        "cone": bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cone_add,
        "cylinder": bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add,
        "sphere": bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add,
        }
    # loop through the dict
    for key, value in objects.items():
        # if key is equal to the obj argument
        if key.lower() == obj.lower():
            # call the value function
            value()
            # break the loop
            break
    return bpy.context.object


def create_collection(name):
    """
    Create a new collection.
    """
    collection = bpy.data.collections.new(name)
    bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(collection)


def move_all_to_coll(coll_name):
    # Set target collection
    move_to = bpy.data.collections[coll_name]
    # Set source collection objects
    move_from = bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].collection.objects
    to_unlink = []
    # If target found and object list not empty
    if move_from:
        # Loop through all objects
        for ob in move_from:
            try:
                move_to.objects.link(ob)
            except RuntimeError:
                pass
            to_unlink.append(ob)
        # Loop through to_unlink list
        for ob in to_unlink:
            move_from.unlink(ob)
        to_unlink.clear()
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a context to methods called from the `bpy.ops.node` module.

```
ctx_override = bpy.context.copy()

for area in bpy.context.screen.areas:
    if area.type == "NODE_EDITOR":
        ctx_override['area'] = area
        break;

bpy.ops.node.tree_socket_add(ctx_override, in_out='IN')
```

Comment: can you please be more precise? 
I can't figure out how to make it work

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6101/poll-failed-context-incorrect-example-bpy-ops-view3d-background-image-add